# How to force search engines to index desktop instead of mobile version of website

Tags: mobile-website

I have a website with both, a desktop and a mobile version. I am using Apache rules to redirect mobile devices to the mobile version of the website. 
The desktop version uses the subdomain "www" and the mobile version "m".
How ever, Google seems to like the mobile version much more than the desktop version, so that the rank of the pages of letter are always worst than the one of the equivalent desktop version. And besides Google indexed much more pages from the mobile version than from the desktop version.

How do I tell Google an other search engines that the mobile version is just for mobile devices? Should a block the subdomain "m" completely with robots.txt? Or is there any way to tell those robots that a specific page like m.mysite.com/a-page is just the mobile version of www.mysite.com/a-page?

Comment: Google will use different user agents when crawling for mobile pages and desktop pages. Are you considering that difference now in your pages?

Comment: I do consider this for the redirect to the mobile site by using this line in htaccess: _RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos"_ What else could I do? Put something in the haeder of each page?